# Closed form formula for summation where bounds are variables

Tags: summation, algorithms, closed-form

$$
\sum_{i=k}^n (2i-1)
$$
I was given the problem shown above. What I did was separate them into two summations as following so it'd be:

$$
2 \sum_{i=k}^n i - \sum_{i=k}^n 1
$$

I know the second summation will be (n-k+1), but for the first summation, since the bounds aren't a numerical answer, I wasn't sure what it would be since a rule that I know is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$

but k starts at 1. Thank you for the help!

Comment: $ \sum\limits_{ i=k}^{n}=\sum\limits_{ i=1}^{n}-\sum\limits_{ i=1}^{k-1}$.

Comment: So essentially the problem is calculating the term $\sum_{i=k}^n i$. Let's start with the normal case:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i =  1+2+3+4+ \ldots + (n-1) + n
$$
We can take some number $k$ (for example $k=5$) and split it there:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i =  \underbrace{1+2+3+4}_{\text{first}}+ \underbrace{5+6+ \ldots + (n-1) + n}_{\text{second}}
$$
What if we want to calculate the "first" and "second" separately? I think you know how to calculate the "first", and we know that the sum of first and second is equal to $\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$... Do you know how to calculate the "second" now?